# Search Server Express Topology Problem

Tags: search-express

Lately I've installed Search Server Express 2010. After configuring it, I tried to test search functionality - content was crawled, and found by the search mechanism, so it was OK. Problem occured when I went entered Topology for Search Service Application: Search Service Application(Central Administration -> Manage services on server -> SharePoint Server Search -> Modify Topology). I can do everything there, but when I click Cancel or Apply Topology Changes it throws me an error:

> An unhandled exception occurred in the
>   user interface.Exception Information:
>   An update conflict has occurred, and
>   you must re-try this action. The
>   object SearchConfigWizardContext
>   Name=8644038a-200f-4fd7-9842-57fc35aee1ca
>   was updated by , in the
>   w3wp (1488) process, on machine
>   .  View the tracing log for
>   more information about the conflict.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID:
>   3d4b97c0-3309-4e6e-aa55-c82d8bc57cdd

Does anybody had similar problem and knows what can be wrong?

Regards

Comment: so, did you do what it said, and checked the ULS log? Use http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer to filter on correlation ID

Answer (score 1):

How did you install it?  You can't access the topology service unless you installed it in a farm configuration (i.e. not stand alone).

Additionally, bear in mind that you can not separate the components on the express edition, they must all reside on a single server.

Comment: I think he is referring to the Search Topology configuration, not the topology service.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the Search Topology configuration is fully operational in Search Server Express, I can't think that there is too much you could usefully do with it. This is all about putting multiple crawl and query components on different servers, which isn't possible with the Express edition. I think this error message is the (none too helpful) result.

If you have it working I would leave the topology configuration alone with Search Server Express.

Comment: I was actually trying to convey the same thing :)

Comment: I'd give you an upvote back, except I'm out of votes today ;-)